# Angular @Output with callback

Tags: angular, callback, rxjs, eventemitter

Is it possible to have a callback with `@Output`?

I have a `FormComponent` which checks validity, and disables the submit button while submitting. Now I'd like to reenable the submit button, when submitting has finished.

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      ...
    </form>
  `
})
class FormComponent {
  form: FormGroup = ...;

  isSubmitting = false;

  @Output()
  submitted = new EventEmitter<MyData>()

  onSubmit() {
    if(this.form.invalid || this.isSubmitting) {
      return;
    }

    this.isSubmitting = true;

    this.submitted.emit(this.form.value);
    // Here I'd like to listen for the result of the parent component
    // something like this...
    // this.submitted.emit(...).subscribe(res => this.isSubmitting = false);
  }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <my-form (submitted)="onSubmitted($event)"></my-form>
  `
})
class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private service: MyService) { }

  onSubmitted(event: MyData) {
    this.service.doSomething(event).pipe(
      tap(res => console.log("service res", res)
    );
    // basically I'd like to `return` this `Observable`,
    // so the `FormComponent` can listen for the completion
  }
}
```

I know, I could use an `@Input()` within `FormComponent` and do something like this:

```js
@Input()
set submitted(val: boolean) {
  this.isSubmitted = val;
}
```

But I'd like to know if there's a simpler / better solution, because `isSubmitted` should be an internal property of `FormComponent`, which should be managed by the component itself and not its parent.

Comment: I think it's more elegant to do it in a service. You can inject the service anywhere you want. I'd go with `isSubmitted$: Subject<boolean>` in a service.

Comment: You mean some kind of `FormService`? Then it must be provided by the `ParentComponent` (because the very same form can be displayed multiple times on the same screen). And then `FormComponent` injects it and observes the `isSubmitted$` stream. Yeah, this might work, too. But I was hoping for something more simple...

Comment: A shorter version would be to use `@ViewChild(FormComponent) form` in the parent and then `form.isSubmitting = false`. Does effectively the same job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitting = true;
    this.submitHandler(this.form.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.isSubmitting = false;
      this.cdr.markForCheck();
    });
  }
```

In the above example code, the function `onSubmit()` is not a *stateless function* and depends upon an *external* handler. Making the function itself *unpredictable* from a testing perspective. When this fails (if it does) you won't know where, why or how. The callback also ricks being executed *after* the component has been *destroyed*.

The problem of being *disabled* is an external state by the consumer of the component. So I would just make it an input binding (like the other answer here). This makes the component more *dry* and easier to test.

```
@Component({
  template: `<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.valid && enabled && onSubmit()"</form>`
})
class FormComponent {
  form: FormGroup = ...;

  @Input()
  enabled = true;

  @Output()
  submitted = new EventEmitter<MyData>()

  onSubmit() {
    // I prefer to do my blocking in the template
    this.submitted.emit(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

The key difference here is that I use `enabled$ | async` below to support `OnPush` change detection. Since the *state* of the component changes asynchronously.

```
@Component({
  template: `<my-form [enabled]="enabled$ | async" (submitted)="onSubmitted($event)"></my-form>`
})
class ParentComponent {
  public enabled$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);

  constructor(private service: MyService) { }

  onSubmitted(event: MyData) {
    this.enabled$.next(false);
    this.service.doSomething(event).pipe(
      tap(res => this.enabled$.next(true)
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
}
```

Comment: In my actual implementation I'd use `this.submitHandler(this.form.value).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$),finalize(this.submitting = false; this.cdr.markForCheck();}).subscribe();`. (That's why I put the comment *"don't forget to unsubscribe on destroy"* `;-)`). Though it won't get executed after destroy. I don't get your point with testing. The `FormComponent` has a special contract, and it only has to work if that contract is fulfilled. So if you don't provide a `submitHandler` or a `submitHandler` that never completes, you didn't fulfill the component's contract. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @BenjaminM what I mean by testing is that the function's internal state is controlled by an external callback. So while unit tests can pass the code can still fail in the wild because the function is not pure.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such callback. At best you can do is do some @Input wiring.

In `parent.component.html`

`<my-form (submitted)="formSubmit($event)" [disableButton]="disableButton"></my-form>`

In `parent.component.ts`

```
disableButton: boolean = false;

formSubmit(myForm) {
 this.disableButton = true; --> disable it here as soon as form submitted.

 this.service.doSomething(event).pipe(
  tap(res => {
  console.log("service res", res);
  this.disableButton = false; // --> enable it here when form submission complete
   }
 ));

}
```

In `child.component.ts`

`@Input() disableButton: boolean`

In `child.component.html`

`<button [disabled]="disableButton?'':null">Submit</button>`

So one way is to implement on these lines.

Comment: Yeah, this is the one solution I already pointed out in the question, using `@Input() set submitted`. But you also have to use `this.cdr.markForCheck()` after `this.disableButton = false` when using `OnPush`.

Comment: Oops! I missed that. Well yes this is one solution. I don't think there is an escape from the parent component in any other solution i could think of. Like one solution can be, using a subject and along with form data send subject as well to parent. When submission is complete enable disabled button through subject received. Other solution is  view child approach you yourself thought of.

Answer (score 0):

You can set isSubmiting in Parent component and provided it as Input to child component. In your case solution will be, initialize isSubmitting in parent component and set it to false. Then when from child component u emit a value on first line of parent callback set isSubmitting to true. Once when logic for onSubmitted is done u can set isSubmitting to false again. All u have to do in child component is to receive isSubmitted as input and set it to input type submit as bind attr [disabled]="isSubmitting"

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way: By passing a handler function as `@Input`:

```js
class FormComponent {
  form: FormGroup = ...;

  isSubmitting = false;

  @Input()
  submitHandler: (value: MyData) => Observable<any>;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  onSubmit() {
    if (!this.form.valid || this.isSubmitting) {
      return;
    }

    this.isSubmitting = true;

    // don't forget to unsubscribe on destroy
    this.submitHandler(this.form.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.isSubmitting = false;
      this.cdr.markForCheck();
    });
  }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <my-form [submitHandler]="submitHandler"></my-form>
  `
})
class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private service: MyService) { }

  submitHandler = (formValue: MyData): Observable<any> => {
    return this.service.doSomething(event);
  };
}
```

That's easy to use and works pretty well. The only "bad" thing is, that it feels like I'm abusing `@Input` for something it wasn't designed.

Answer (score 0):

And another solution using a template variable:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <my-form (submitted)="onSubmit($event, form)" #form></my-form>
  `
})
class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private service: MyService) { }

  onSubmit(event: MyData, form: FormComponent) {
    // don't forget to unsubscribe
    this.service.doSomething(event).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        form.setSubmitting(false);
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
}
```

```js
class FormComponent {
  form: FormGroup = ...;

  isSubmitting = false;

  @Output()
  submitted = new EventEmitter<MyData>()

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  setSubmitting(val: boolean) {
    this.isSubmitting = val;
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (!this.form.valid || this.isSubmitting) {
      return;
    }

    this.isSubmitting = true;

    this.submitted.emit(this.form.value);
  }
}
```